# Is is possible to disable TCP timestamping per-connection?

Tags: linux, tcp

I am writing simple TCP/IP client (in python, later perhaps using ASIO or Qt) for an embedded system which rejects connections when the first SYN packet uses TCP timestamps.

I can make it working by `echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps` but I am looking for a way which can change that setting for a particular connection (or process) only.

Is that even possible? Is the `/proc/sys/..` only setting a default for all TCP connections, or does it for all of them to be that way?